# Not all sites are returning Hi Res icons

Tags: bug

In the /sites method, not all the sites return `high_resolution_icon_url` field. (e.g. Personal Finance and Money) Although if you add "@2" to the normal resolution icon you can see a high res image does exist.

EDIT: It seems its the beta sites that don't return this field.